# Inconsistent week of year number for December 31 in Postgres... 1, 52, or 53

Tags: postgresql, date

While experimenting with grouping by week of year I found that week of year returned in Postgres for December 31 varies by year with unexpected results (at least to me). The result is usually 52 (good), sometimes 53, and often 1.

53 I can understand as it's counting weeks based on a specific day of the week so counting by that day could end up with 53 weeks. Not great, but understandable.

But why does Postgres often say December 31 is in the first week of the year? How does that make sense?

Example:

```
      SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM DATE '2000-12-31') AS "Week",'Week2000' AS "Year"
UNION SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM DATE '2001-12-31') AS "Week",'Week2001' AS "Year"
UNION SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM DATE '2002-12-31') AS "Week",'Week2002' AS "Year"
UNION SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM DATE '2003-12-31') AS "Week",'Week2003' AS "Year"
UNION SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM DATE '2004-12-31') AS "Week",'Week2004' AS "Year"
UNION SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM DATE '2005-12-31') AS "Week",'Week2005' AS "Year"
UNION SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM DATE '2006-12-31') AS "Week",'Week2006' AS "Year"
UNION SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM DATE '2007-12-31') AS "Week",'Week2007' AS "Year"
UNION SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM DATE '2008-12-31') AS "Week",'Week2008' AS "Year"
UNION SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM DATE '2009-12-31') AS "Week",'Week2009' AS "Year"
UNION SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM DATE '2010-12-31') AS "Week",'Week2010' AS "Year"
UNION SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM DATE '2011-12-31') AS "Week",'Week2011' AS "Year"
UNION SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM DATE '2012-12-31') AS "Week",'Week2012' AS "Year"
UNION SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM DATE '2013-12-31') AS "Week",'Week2013' AS "Year"
UNION SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM DATE '2014-12-31') AS "Week",'Week2014' AS "Year"
UNION SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM DATE '2015-12-31') AS "Week",'Week2015' AS "Year"
ORDER BY "Year"
```

Results:

```
Week   Year
-----  ---------
52     Week2000
1      Week2001
1      Week2002
1      Week2003
53     Week2004
52     Week2005
52     Week2006
1      Week2007
1      Week2008
53     Week2009
52     Week2010
52     Week2011
1      Week2012
1      Week2013
1      Week2014
53     Week2015
```

I've tested with specifying a full timestamp and not just date and that has the same results, regardless of what hour of day I include in the timestamp.

December 29 & 30 also can result in 1, 52, or 53 results.

December 27 & 28 can result in 52 or 53.

Comment: Is is the definition: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html ISO 8601 `By definition, ISO weeks start on Mondays and the first week of a year contains January 4 of that year.`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PostgreSQL uses the ISO8601 definition.  This means that weeks start on Monday, and the first week of the year is the week that has Jan 4.  If Jan 4 falls on a Tuesday for example, Dec 31 is in week 1 of that year.

Comment: You can think of it sortof like a fiscal year.  The ISO8601 year does not start on January 1 -- it starts on whatever week, starting with Monday, contains January 4.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation:

> It's recommended to use the isoyear field together with week to get consistent results.

Example:

```sql
SELECT 
  extract(isoyear FROM date_field), 
  extract(week FROM date_field), 
  ...
```